# Query does not return child collections

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I still struggle with this, why each of 'Category' items returns null 'Task' collections. I do have data in the database, what am I missing?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the query:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllForUser(string name)
{
    return _ctx.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == name)
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Categories)
                     .Include(x => x.Tasks).ToList();    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is falling into [Ignored Includes](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#ignored-includes) case:

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored.

As explained in the link, if you add the following to your DbContext `OnConfiguring`:

```
optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning));
```

then instead `null` collection you'll get `InvalidOperationException` containing something like this inside the error message:

> The Include operation for navigation: 'x.Tasks' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results.

So how to fix that? Apparently the requirement is to start the query from the entity for which you want to add includes. In your case, you should start from `_ctx.Categories`. But in order to apply the same filter, you need to add the reverse navigation property of the `Application.Users` to the `Category` class:

```
public class Category
{
    // ...
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now the following will work:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllForUser(string name)
{
    return _ctx.Categories
        .Where(c => c.ApplicationUser.UserName == name)
        .Include(c => c.Tasks)
        .ToList();    
}
```

Comment: This is perfect Ivan, great explanation, I have tested against what you have mentioned above to fully understand it, and you nailed the solution. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllForUser(string name)
{
    return _ctx.Users
                .Include(u => u.Categories)
                .Include(u => u.Categories.Select(c => c.Tasks))
                .Where(x => x.UserName == name)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Categories)
                .ToList();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.